# How can I get the user's AppData folder path

Tags: go

I want to store some files in `appdata` path, but I don't know how to get it in Go.

Answer (score 17):

There are already functions for this in the os package, see [here](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#UserCacheDir) for reference:

```
package main

func main() {
    os.UserHomeDir() // C:\Users\YourUser
    os.UserCacheDir() // C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Local
    os.UserConfigDir() // C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Roaming
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It resides in user home folder, so you can get user folder and append AppData:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "runtime"
)

func UserHomeDir() string {
    if runtime.GOOS == "windows" {
        home := os.Getenv("HOMEDRIVE") + os.Getenv("HOMEPATH")
        if home == "" {
            home = os.Getenv("USERPROFILE")
        }
        return home
    }
    return os.Getenv("HOME")
}

func main() {
    homeDir := UserHomeDir()
    fmt.Println(homeDir + "\\AppData")
}
```

Comment: Tks.And I just know a better way to get it.That's using `os.Getenv('APPDATA')`